# how to make text area and img tags read only after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<div class="prp_div">   
<div id="img_div1"> 
<?php
include_once('config.php');


$disp=mysql_query("select * from pop") ;
$out = mysql_fetch_array($disp);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $out[3];?>" style="width:100%; height:100%" />
</div>


<div id="comment_left">

<b>Graphic Text:</b><br/>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="gtext" name="gtext" placeholder="Enter Graphic Text..." class="input" >
<?php echo $out['gtext']; ?>
</textarea><br/>


<b>Caption:</b><br/>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="caption" name="caption" placeholder="Enter Caption..." class="input">
 <?php echo $out['caption']; ?>
</textarea>


<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
```

I have a form that contains one image tag in a div and two text areas.Once i enter the data and press the submit button i want these fields to be read only..can anyone help me on this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a php variable.

```
<?php
    $isSubmitted = false;
   if (!empty($_POST))//checks request
        $isSubmitted = true;

?>

<!--on your textarea-->
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="caption" name="caption" placeholder="Enter Caption..." class="input" 
<?php
    echo $isSubmitted== true? 'disabled' : '' //add 'disabled' tag in element if isSubmitted is true
 ?>
><?php echo $out['caption']; ?></textarea>
```

sorry if my code is a bit dirty.

EDIT

this alone might work.

```
<!--on your textarea-->
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="caption" name="caption" placeholder="Enter Caption..." class="input" 
<?php
    echo !empty($out['caption'])? 'disabled' : '' //add 'disabled' tag in element if $out['caption'] is not empty
 ?>
><?php echo $out['caption']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you...it works partially...field will be read only after submission but once i refresh the page it becomes editable..

Comment: i don't think image tags are clickable alone, so they should be fine. I don't understand what you want them to do though.

Comment: like text area i want browse button to be disabled so that no one can upload new image..

Comment: you mean the input type= file?

Comment: just add the same php code inside its tag.

<?php
    echo !empty($out['caption'])? 'disabled' : ''
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

This will the button:

```
<button onclick = "disableFields()" type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE"> </button>
```

This will be your javascript:

```
   function disableFields(){
   document.getElementById('gtext').disable;
   document.getElementById('caption').disable;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
<input type="button" class="buttonclass" name="submit" value="save">  
    $(".buttonclass").click(function(){
    $(".input").attr('readonly', true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" onSubmit="dsiableAllInputs();">
```

Call following code on submission of form

```
function dsiableAllInputs(){
    jQuery(":input").prop('disabled', true);
    jQuery(":textarea").prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more user-friendly way :

```
$(".buttonclass").click(function(){
    $(".input").attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following way

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" onSubmit="makeReadOnly();">
 ......
 ......
 ......
</form>

<script>
function makeReadOnly()
{
   $('#gtext').attr('readOnly', true);
   $('#caption').attr('readOnly', true);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use disable function on the elements you wanted.
My suggestion is to give a class name like "toReadOnly" to those particular elements and then getElementsByClassName and disable those elements.

```
<script>
function onyourRequirement()
{
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("toReadOnly")
for(element : elements)
      element.disable
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

My Bad, Use this

```
    <form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="myFunction()">

     <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="gtext" name="gtext"  
           placeholder="Enter Graphic Text..." class="input" >
              aaass
     </textarea><br/>

      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="caption" name="caption" 
         placeholder="Enter Caption..." class="input"> </textarea>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>

     <script>
      function myFunction() {
        alert("The form was submitted");
        document.getElementById('gtext').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('caption').disabled = true;
         }
      </script>
```